# getting the description of a table using Google bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am new to bigquery. First thing, I would have liked to do the SQL equivalent of DESC using Google bigquery. 
I did:

```
DESC `paj.dw.MY_TABLE`;
```

But I get:

```
Statement not supported: DescribeStatement
```

There are mentions of INFORMATION_SCHEMA in beta version, but I get:

```
Syntax error: Unexpected identifier "INFORMATION_SCHEMA"
```

How do you do it yourself ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, you can also run the following from the console command line (cloud shell)
[image: Cloud Shell]

`bq show --schema --format=prettyjson dataset.table`

I prefer this for tables that have nested records.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for me..

Comment: 4 years later?  Write a new question

Answer (score 2):

You could do like

```
SELECT
 * EXCEPT(is_generated, generation_expression, is_stored, is_updatable)
FROM
 paj.dw.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
 table_name="MY_TABLE"
```

For other information schema views and example see this [page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables#columns_view).

Answer (score 2):

Take first table in public dataset for example:

```
SELECT column_name, is_nullable, data_type
FROM `bigquery-public-data.austin_311.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`
WHERE table_name="311_request"
```

You get:

```
+--------------------------+-------------+-----------+
|       column_name        | is_nullable | data_type |
+--------------------------+-------------+-----------+
| unique_key               | YES         | STRING    |
| complaint_type           | YES         | STRING    |
| complaint_description    | YES         | STRING    |
| owning_department        | YES         | STRING    |
| source                   | YES         | STRING    |
| status                   | YES         | STRING    |
| status_change_date       | YES         | TIMESTAMP |
| created_date             | YES         | TIMESTAMP |
| last_update_date         | YES         | TIMESTAMP |
| close_date               | YES         | TIMESTAMP |
| incident_address         | YES         | STRING    |
| street_number            | YES         | STRING    |
| street_name              | YES         | STRING    |
| city                     | YES         | STRING    |
| incident_zip             | YES         | INT64     |
| county                   | YES         | STRING    |
| state_plane_x_coordinate | YES         | STRING    |
| state_plane_y_coordinate | YES         | FLOAT64   |
| latitude                 | YES         | FLOAT64   |
| longitude                | YES         | FLOAT64   |
| location                 | YES         | STRING    |
| council_district_code    | YES         | INT64     |
| map_page                 | YES         | STRING    |
| map_tile                 | YES         | STRING    |
+--------------------------+-------------+-----------+
```